# How create text background in zend pdf

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-pdf

I am new to the ***zend-framework***.

I created a **pdf in zend** and I want to **set text background with the color**.

like

[image]

please help........

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Have you read Zend's documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try to read :  http://devzone.zend.com/article/12492

That will give answer to all of your doubts.......

Comment: this link is 404 broken :(

Comment: Ohh, if you are still looking for the content on the page then you could find it using web archive. I tried that and got that for you: http://web.archive.org/web/20120118050308/http://devzone.zend.com/1776/creating-pdf-documents-with-zend-framework/

Comment: Sorry for replying so late, I rarely use StackOverflow nowadays. :(